# Session not saving after login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session-cookies

I have a problem with express-session. When I try to login I have to save my userdata in cookies and after redirect get it on home page. Now after redirect my cookie is clearing and I have default cookie without some data

```
const authRoute = require('./routes/auth')

mongoose.connect(
    process.env.DB_CONNECT,
    { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
    () => {
        console.log('Connected to DB')
    });

//Middleware 
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(session({
    name: 'sid',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
    secret: process.env.SESS_SECRET,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
        sameSite: true,
        secure: false
    }
}))


app.use('/api/user', authRoute)
```

**Routes file**

```
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.session);
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.status(200).send(req.session.user)
    } else res.status(403).send({ error: 'You need to login first' })
})

router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    ...
    req.session.user = { id: user._id, username: user.name, email: user.email }
    req.session.save()
    //CREATE AND ASSIGN TOKER 

    const token = jsw.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET)
    res.header('auth-toker', token).send(user)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Windows Defender or other anti virus software. Those may not allow the connection to go through

Comment: But other sites cookies is saving